# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ckpt_path' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, pickle, argparse

I am facing this issue even if the 'ckpt' path is not defined before.
few solutions are available to make the variable global. Bu i don't have any idea how to implement this in below code .
traceback for the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "make_feature_maps.py", line 186, in <module>
main(argv=sys.argv)
File "make_feature_maps.py", line 163, in main
checkpoint_path=ckpt_path)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ckpt_path' referenced before assignment
```

**For the above traceback line 163 is :**

```
predict_generator = model.predict(input_fn = lambda: input_fn(None,batch_size=1, n_steps=None,shuffle=False,n_epochs=1, args=args),checkpoint_path=ckpt_path)
```

**and line 186 is :**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':     #line-184
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)   #line185
main(argv=sys.argv)    #line-186
```

**Code for main is :**

```
def main(argv):
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
add_args.for_general(parser)
add_args.for_inference(parser)
add_args.for_evaluation(parser)
add_args.for_feature(parser)
add_args.for_lstm(parser)
args = parser.parse_args()

config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_summary_steps=float('inf'),
                                  log_step_count_steps=10)

params = {
    'image_size': args.image_size,
    'gazemap_size': args.gazemap_size,
    'model_dir': args.model_dir
  }
model = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=model_fn,
    model_dir=args.model_dir,
    config=config,
    params=params)

#determine which checkpoint to restore
if args.model_iteration is None:
    best_ckpt_dir = os.path.join(args.model_dir, 'best_ckpt')
    if os.path.isdir(best_ckpt_dir):
        ckpt_name = [f.split('.index')[0] for f in os.listdir(best_ckpt_dir) if f.endswith('.index')][0]
        ckpt_path = os.path.join(best_ckpt_dir, ckpt_name)
        args.model_iteration = ckpt_name.split('-')[1]
else:
    ckpt_name = 'model.ckpt-'+args.model_iteration
    ckpt_path = os.path.join(args.model_dir, ckpt_name)    


K.clear_session()
predict_generator = model.predict(
    input_fn = lambda: input_fn(None, 
        batch_size=1, n_steps=None, 
        shuffle=False,
        n_epochs=1, args=args),
    checkpoint_path=ckpt_path)

output_dir = os.path.join(args.data_dir, 'image_features_'+args.feature_name)
if not os.path.isdir(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `ckpt_path` is not defined because `args.model_iteration is not None` and `os.path.isdir(best_ckpt_dir)` is False.